# error in getting the report excel

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I have a function for excel report
I use a node-xlsx

function:

```
async function getReport(q) {
  const headers = [
    'Day',
    'Time',
    'Number'
  ]
  const rows = await getList({ ...q, pagination: { offset: 0, limit: 100000 } })
  res.attachment('additional-check.xlsx')
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
  const file = nodeXlsx.build([{
    name: 'Report',
    data: [headers].concat(rows.map(it => [
      moment(it.checked_at).tz('Europe/Moscow').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      moment(it.checked_at).tz('Europe/Moscow').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      it.id
    ])),
  }])
  res.status(200).send(file)
}
router.get('/additional-checks/xlsx', action(({ q }) => additionalCheck.getReport(q)))
```

where i did made a mistake?

Comment: Can you explain what's going wrong?

Comment: I want to download the report, but I get mistake, when i do this